# can't add a link to an entire div section

Tags: list, html, hyperlink, tinymce, anchor

I have a problem with TinyMCE in Joomla 2.5.4. I have tried for a few days now to add a link to a div section (like <a href="#"> <div> something< </div> </a>) but failed, the anchor is stripped from the HTML section because TinyMCE sees that as being wrong in HTML4. After a 3 days research I gave up and instead of a div i used a unordered list.

Now when i try to add a link to a list item (like <a href="#"> <li> <p> something </p> </li> </a>) TinyMCE rearranges everything and moves the anchor inside of the list item (like <li> <a href="#"> <p> something </p> &=lt;/a> </li>).

I have tried pretty much everything from valid_elements : "*[*]" to text filter: No Filtering but i ran low on ideas.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why not turn TinyMCE editor off and choose `none` as your editor. Type in your html then if you really really need an editor, turn it on again once you have the html saved.

Comment: On a different note, please consider supporting http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers for Joomla related questions.

Comment: I was actually hoping there would be a solution to somehow "fix" tinyMCE (like modify it's php file somehow) rather then to turn it of. I have a huge amount of content to add and tinyMCE really helps saving a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with TinyMCE's html5 options: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/html5_formats.php

Hit "view source" to see how they're doing it. It's mainly this option inside tinyMCE.init:

```
schema: "html5",
```